# Generic List to List of string for single Property

Tags: c#, list

Am having a Generic List say of class `Student` with

```
ID
Name
Class
```

as Properties.

I  need to convert this into a `List<string>` with only Name property of `List<student>`
What i did?

```
List<student> stud;
List<string> str;
foreach (var item in stud)
 {
 str.Add(item.Name);
 }
```

Is there a easier way i can do this w/o using for each ?

Thanks

Comment: Why not call it `students`, much more readable than saving a couple characters.

Comment: @YuriyFaktorovich Indeed; *stud* is something quite different.

Comment: Agree Yuiry. Just i came up with some demo example for question purpose :)

Comment: Check out my answer too. It's at the very bottom and is a slightly different way of expressing the same.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use Linq `Select` to project your result:

```
List<string> str = stud.Select(s => s.Name).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var str = stud.Select(s => s.Name).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

use linq

```
List<student> stud;
List<string> str;

str = stud.Select(s => s.Name).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Just as an alternative to the LINQ-based solutions proposed:

```
List<string> str = stud.ConvertAll(s => s.Name);
```

I'd probably use `Select`/`ToList` rather than [`List<T>.ConvertAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73fe8cwf.aspx) because it's more flexible (it wouldn't matter if you changed `stud` to be an array later, for example) but it's worth being aware of `ConvertAll` anyway. In particular:

- It's available out of the box in .NET 2
- It's very slightly more efficient than `Select`/`ToList`, because the transformation knows the size to start with. (That knowledge is effectively lost in `Select`.)

Answer (score 1):

The above answers are all in the method syntax for linq. I 'll give you the query syntax for the same-

```
List<string> str = (from item in stud select Name).ToList();
```